# How to create a loop to simplify this script so I can perform more iterations

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, math, while-loop

Initial Conditions

```
Re1i = 3.2*10**7
Re2i = (3/4)*Re1i
lambda1i = ((1/(-2*np.log10((ks/3.7) + (5.74/(Re1i**0.9)))))**2)
lambda2i = ((1/(-2*np.log10((ks/3.7) + (5.74/(Re2i**0.9)))))**2)
V1i = np.sqrt((dh*2*g*d1*d2)/((l1*lambda1i*d2) + (lambda2i*l2*((A1**2)/(A2**2)))))
```

Perform Iteration without loop

```
Re1ii = (rho*V1i*d1)/mu
Re2ii = (3/4)*Re1i
lambda1ii = ((1/(-2*np.log10((ks/3.7) + (5.74/(Re1ii**0.9)))))**2)
lambda2ii = ((1/(-2*np.log10((ks/3.7) + (5.74/(Re2ii**0.9)))))**2)
V1ii = np.sqrt((dh*2*g*d1*d2)/((l1*lambda1ii*d2) + (lambda2ii*l2*((A1**2)/(A2**2)))))

Re1iii = ...
```

I am not sure how to get this process to occur without manually assigning new variables for each iteration. I am aware that a loop would be able to complete this process, but I don't know how to implement said loop into the script.

I tried to create a for loop to iterate the variables however as they are dependent on each other I do not know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than creating many i, ii, iii... variables, I would recommend storing each type of information in a list. This way you append as you loop and can easily access all the data. So:

```
Re1_list = [Re1i, Re2ii,...]
# = [3.2*10**7, (rho*V1i*d1)/mu,...]
Re2_list = [Re2i,...]
...
```

Comment: Thanks! What would I put where you have placed the # so that i can assign the values to the variables.

Comment: As Re1i, Re1ii are undefined.

Comment: I'm not saying to assign everything at once. Rather, start Re1_list as an empty list [], then append values for Re1i, Re1ii,... as you compute them